# Is it possible to perform separate network thread within a same activity without wait?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I am performing two class which is extending `ASyncTask` and both have different functions but because of the `second` class my first class is lagging. So what i want to know is, is there any better solution to code in such a way that both of the operation will perform the task without making other operation to wait?

**Updated with code**
For the first call in the `onCreate()`

```
new connection().execute(); //
```

Some task performed by the same class called

```
 public class connection extends AsyncTask {
    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object... arg0) {
       //some operation
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
        super.onPostExecute(o);
        String m = String.valueOf(o);
        if (o != null) {
           someoperation
        } else {
            edittxt.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            edittxt.setText("No Internet Connection");
        }
    }
}
```

similarly i am performing the other class that i have.

Comment: We need your code & LogCat outputs to help you

Comment: Put your second class works in AsyncTask

Comment: Instead of Async task try to use AsyncLoader ....
Which use multithreading for performing any task ..
2nd option intentservice also....

Comment: Or you could think about creating a service and put second async task there

Comment: @Amsheer i have that within `Asyntask`

Comment: Hm, are you sure that if you'll remove first task there will be no "lagging" ?

Comment: @NikMyers yes sir, i have checked if i remove the second task the first task    pulls out the output instantly but it's not the same for the second case where i have both the task

Comment: i meant you should remove first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#executeOnExecutor%28java.util.concurrent.Executor,%20Params...%29) with [`THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR), the default executor is [`SERIAL_EXECUTOR`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#SERIAL_EXECUTOR).

Comment: sir, can you please elaborate

Comment: Instead of `new connection().execute();` use `new connection().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);` This will run the tasks in parallel instead serially (which is the default).

Answer (score 0):

You can create two separate threads and perform your operations. It will quarantine, that all operations will be performed async.

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();

        Thread operation1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                doOperation1();
                handler.run(new Runnable(){
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        onPostExecute1();
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        Thread operation2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                doOperation2();
                handler.run(new Runnable(){
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        onPostExecute2();
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        operation1.start();
        operation2.start();
```